# Save view state using HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I thought I might try to use local storage for a way to save a session state but the api is a little confusing to me.

I have a search results view that can have two toggled states to return the results. They can be returned in a grid view, or a list view. The user can select the preferred view by clicking on the icon. Once the user clicks on one of the icons, I would like to store that as a state in the local storage so when user comes back they don't have to click again.

html

```
 <div class="cbp-vm-options">
   <a href="#" class="cbp-vm-grid cbp-vm-selected"></a>
   <a href="#" class="cbp-vm-list"></a>
 </div>
```

Local storage code

```
function saveViewState() {
    if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {
         return false;
     }
    localStorage["grid.view.state"] = gViewState;

    //Not sure where to go from here
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) then you don't need to worry too much about the API and you can focus on the nice clear examples and not need to worry about older browsers. Here's a quote from the site to show some examples:

> // Store 'marcus' at 'username'
> store.set('username', 'marcus')
>
> // Get 'username'
> store.get('username')
>
> // Remove 'username'
> store.remove('username')

Comment: How would I get the state of that users selection using store.js? The github page doesn't really demonstrate anything like this.

Comment: LocalStorage is soooo simple, you don't need a library to use it.

Comment: @Michael: And what about handling IE6/IE7 that don't support it?

Comment: @Ian Your requirements may differ, but I don't support IE6/7, it has <1% usage worldwide.

Comment: So can someone help with the answer please?

Comment: @Michael true, I'm used to building for government systems which are predominantly IE6 but don't have an pursue world connection

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5a03a5ec/1/

HTML

```
<div class="cbp-vm-options">
    <a href="#" class="cbp-vm-grid" data-state="grid"></a>
    <a href="#" class="cbp-vm-list" data-state="list"></a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cbp-vm-options a {
    opacity: 0.50;
    transition-duration: 800ms;    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: black;
}

.cbp-vm-options a.cbp-vm-selected {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cbp-vm-grid {
}

.cbp-vm-list {

}

#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#content .item {
    border: 10px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content.grid .item {
    width: 25%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function() {

    var cbp_vm_options, content;


    // This function sets the localStorage variable
    function setState(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);

        var new_state = event.target.dataset.state;

        if(document.querySelector('.cbp-vm-selected'))
            document.querySelector('.cbp-vm-selected').classList.remove('cbp-vm-selected');
        event.target.classList.add('cbp-vm-selected')

        console.log(new_state);
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('view_state', new_state);
        updateUi();
    }

    // This function updates the ui for the user depending on the value
    // of 'vew_state'. The function is called whenever the value changes.
    function updateUi(event) {
        content.classList.toggle('grid');

        var state = localStorage.getItem('view_state');

        if(state === 'grid') {
            content.classList.add('grid');
            cbp_vm_options.querySelector('.cbp-vm-grid').classList.add('cbp-vm-selected');
        } else {
            content.classList.remove('grid');            
            cbp_vm_options.querySelector('.cbp-vm-list').classList.add('cbp-vm-selected');
        }

    }



    function init() {

        cbp_vm_options = document.querySelector('.cbp-vm-options'),
        content = document.querySelector('#content');


        updateUi();

        cbp_vm_options.addEventListener('click', setState);

    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);



})();
```

Comment: Trying to refactor this without using a form and going off the code that needs to be used but no joy.

Comment: @ndesign11  That's fine, so instead of using a 'change' event handler, you would use a 'click' handler

Comment: @ndesign11 I've updated the answer to make it closer to your HTML